# How to get the previous text value of a div by clicking a html item?

Tags: jquery, siblings

In the image below is the HTML code: 
[image]

and this is my js code:

```
$(".salveazaTransaSuma").click(function(){
   var payment_name = $(this).siblings().previous(".transaContentEdit").text();
   alert(payment_name);
});
```

So I want to get the text value from the `transaContentEdit` class, when i click on the `salveazaTransa` class. Don't Worry about the white spaces before and after the text value ("Servicii programare Transa 1"). Appearantly my code doesn't work. It gives me an error in firebug "TypeError: $(...).siblings(...).previous is not a function". Any idea how to hande this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your image, you can use:

```
$(".salveazaTransaSuma").click(function(){
   var payment_name = $(this).closest('.litransa').prev().find(".transaContentEdit").text();
   alert(payment_name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `prev` not `previous`

```
$(".salveazaTransaSuma").click(function(){
   var payment_name = $(this).closest('div.litrans.suma').prev().find(".transaContentEdit").text();
   alert(payment_name);
});
```

Comment: Thx for responding . it not gives me the error, but I still get an empty alert and not the value ("Servicii programare Transa 1").

Comment: Can you put html you have in the question, your selector chain need revision too.

Answer (score 1):

`previous` is not a function use `prev`.

```
var payment_name = $(this).closest('.litransa').prev(".transaContentEdit").text();
```

Comment: Thx for responding . it not gives me the error, but I still get an empty alert and not the value ("Servicii programare Transa 1").